# disable GPU on ubuntu server

Tags: server, nvidia

I am using ubuntu server 20.04.2 on an old HP media desktop PC with an Nvidia graphics card. As I am using it as a webserver I don't need the graphics card to run. I installed the webserver with the graphics card attached as there is no onboard graphics card. Now when I remove the graphics card and restart the computer it does not start and the fan makes a huge noise.

What should be the strategy to remove the graphics card and make it work? Or there is any software disable switch?

Comment: Why did the graphics card need to be removed?

Comment: because its fan is running, it's consuming energy without doing anything.